# how to highlight imported functions in python code?

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, elpy

`python-mode` or `elpy-mode` in Emacs only highlight the basic Python library functions.  If you work a lot with other libraries like `numpy` and `matplotlib`, would be nice to have these functions and classes also highlighted. Is there a way?